# Matrix calculus with complex

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, normal-distribution, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus

I'm looking for a simplification of the following expression with a "norm-writing" :
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 (\bar{z}-\bar{\mu})^{T}& (z-\mu)^{T}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\Gamma &C \\ 
 \bar{C}& \bar{\Gamma}
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
z-\mu\\ 
\bar{z}-\bar{\mu}
\end{pmatrix}$$
with $z\in \mathbb{C}^{K}, \mu\in \mathbb{C}^{K},\Gamma\in \mathbb{C}^{K\times K},C\in \mathbb{C}^{K\times K}$$

For example, with an easier case :

$$(x-x_{0})^{T}\Sigma^{T}\Sigma(x-x_{0})=\left \| \Sigma(x-x_{0}) \right \|_{2}^{2}$$

with $x\in \mathbb{C}^{N}, x_{0}\in \mathbb{C}^{N},\Sigma\in \mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$

Notes :

- $\bar{x}$ denotes the complex conjugated
- $x^{T}$ denotes the transpose
- I imagine a expression like this : $\left \| U(z-\mu) \right \|_{2}^{2}$ with U a complex matrix and a demonstration with the complex conjugate transpose $x^{*}$ but I can't see where to go
- If you want to know where this expression come from, it's a part of the probability density fonction for complex normal distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution section "density function")

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HINT (hopefully it serves your purpose):

According to [block-based matrix inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion), say you define $$\begin{bmatrix} \Gamma & C \\ \overline{C} & \overline{\Gamma} \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \Lambda_{aa} & \Lambda_{ab} \\ \Lambda_{ba} & \Lambda_{bb} \end{bmatrix} \ ,$$
then $$\left[\left(\overline{z} - \overline{u}\right)^T \ \ \left({z} - {u}\right)^T\right]  \begin{bmatrix} \Lambda_{aa} & \Lambda_{ab} \\ \Lambda_{ba} & \Lambda_{bb} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\left(\overline{z} - \overline{u}\right) \\ \left({z} - {u}\right)\end{bmatrix}  \ .$$ Now you can perform "completing the square"...

But there are some cross-coupling terms, which will remain in quadratic form.